# PHP OO: Overriding properties of abstract class

Tags: php, oop

Please could someone advise?

We have an abstract base class with a few properties and some methods.

The methods(with parameters) are being called from inherited classes with the common intention of setting the passed parameters to the properties of the base class except they don't appear to override the default value.

If I set a value(for testing purposes) in the constructor of the abstract(base) class it works fine and anything else passed to the constructor works but what we want to do is get the setErrors method to actually set the value of the property.

**Example:**

```
//abstract base class

private $errors = array();//the property we want to overide

public function __construct()
{
$this->errors[] = "This is a required field";//for testing purposes only this works
}

public function setErrors($error)
{
var_dump($error);//this proves that $error is passing something...
$this->errors[] = $error;//this doesnt work(override the property)
var_dump($this->error);//the property now has the $error value...
}

public function getErrors()
{
return "<li>".implode("</li>\n",$this->errors);
}
```

I'm not sure if this is something to do with the base class being abstract i.e. as it doesnt get instantiated. Please could someone explain why this doesn't work? 
Thanks in advance for taking an interest.

Edit
WE ARE NOT TRYING TO INHERIT THE PRIVATE PROPERTY FROM THE BASE CLASS

What we want to do is override the property with the set method and then use a public get method to return the property.

Comment: What's the problem? [It works fine](http://codepad.org/nCe6bMOI).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should declare $errors as protected instead of private. Read more about [Class and Objects visibility](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.visibility.php) ;-)

**Update:**

Ok, maybe I understand your problem now :P

Try to modify your setErrors like so:

```
    public function setErrors($error)
    {
        var_dump($error);//this proves that $error is passing something...
        $this->errors = (array) $error;//this works (override the property)
    }
```

Comment: Sorry Steve, but it isn't clear what are you expecting to your code. Could you update your question with a complete example, the expected result and the actual one?

Comment: Francesco, Ive updated the code. Basically we have a property 'errors' and set/get methods. If you ignore the constructor we are trying to add a value to the property with the set method except its not doing this. If you set the value of the property 'error' in the constructor like in the code you get the desired results but obviously we dont want to do that, we want the setter method to do this.

Comment: [Your code works][1] :-)
I just added an "s" to var_dump($this->error**s**)


  [1]: http://codepad.org/GXQYkcUY

Comment: Thanks Francesco, it must be something else causing this then because its not working but the framework Ive built is a bit more extensive than the code weve talked about. You have helped put this to rest though so technically youve answered the question, cheers, especially for testing. You deserve a beer for that :-)

Answer (score 5):

You're declaring the `errors` field as private so only the class where it's declared (the abstract superclass) has access to it.

You can either make it `protected` so subclasses can access it or implement the `setErrors` method in the superclass.

Comment: Beat me to it :P (the superclass part anyway)

Comment: As stated below we are not trying to access the private property via inherited classes.

Comment: @Steve "override the property with the set method and then use a public get method to return the property." This doesn't make any sense. What is overriding a property with a method? You cannot touch the property in the subclasses, only if the superclass exposes a method to manipulate it (or via reflection)

Comment: The base class has the property 'errors' and a couple of methods to set and get the property however the set method is not 'setting' the data to the property. When we call the get method we get a null.

Comment: @Steve Then show us the implementation of that get method that's not working.

Comment: Get method is fine and works, its the set method that doesnt. Its like I can only set values to my properties via its constructor for this abstract base class which is why I was asking to see if theres anything weird about abstract classes I dont know about. Thanks anyway Arte.

Answer (score 0):

`private` members are not visible in inherited classes. To do this you must change the visibility to `protected`.

Comment: We are not trying to access any members of the base class via inherited classes. We are calling a base class method from a subclass and passing a parameter. We then set the property with the passed parameter and call a get method to return the value of the property but as the question goes...the property is not being overridden.

Comment: Please add some example code and the actual as well as the expected results. This doesn't make sense to me - but perhaps I'm just not understanding the problem correctly.

Comment: The property should get set via the 'setErrors()' method in the same class but its not, all the code is there. We would then use a public get method to return the property that can be called from a subclass.

Comment: Sorry, this doesn't make sense. `$this->errors[] = $error` even does not *override* the property, it rather adds `$error` to the `$this->errors` array.

Comment: Thanks Stefan, would you know the right way of doing this then because basically we want the value passed in $error to be stored in the base class property 'error'?

Answer (score 0):

I find something that may help you.  Am not claiming as answer :-(

http://www.triconsole.com/php/oop.php

http://www.killerphp.com/tutorials/object-oriented-php/php-objects-page-4.php

Answer (score 0):

what is basically happening is that php will add the new error to the present error array.
eg.

```
$this->error[0]="this fie..." //default value
$this->error[1]=`$error       //the actual set error
```